# MySQL question: The right way to calculate some data from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

We have a table `A` in which we store data about user investments; example columns `user_id`, `project_id`, `amount`.

We also have a table `B` in which we store data about projects and the total amount of investments; columns `project_id` and `total_amount`.

With PHP we can count the amount from `A` and write `total_amount` to `B`.

**The question:** Is it possible at the MYSQL level to automatically calculate data in order to avoid unnecessary operations in PHP?

If Yes, could you show me an example?

Comment: You just need table A. To calculate total amount you can use SUM function in MySQL

Comment: Yep, in general, avoid storing derived data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to calculate total amount:

```
"SELECT SUM(amount) as total_amount from table_a group by project_id"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tableB
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT project_id, SUM(amount) total_amount
    FROM tableA
    GROUP BY project_id
) amounts
ON amounts.project_id = tableB.project_id
SET tableB.code_counter=amounts.total_amount
```

This should work.